# Populating SelectableItemsView with items

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to put together a selectableItemsView to populate with a list of objects and for some reason, I'm not getting any items to show in the SelectableItemsView; I only get a white blank space where the items are supposed to be. TermView is inserted into the mainPage and is supposed to contain Term information as well as a Class list  that is displayed via SelectableItemsView. I've also tried using a ListView and its giving me the same problem.

**TermView.xaml.cs constructor**

```
public TermView(int termId)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Term = new Term(termId);
            this.BindingContext = this.Term;
        }
```

**TermView.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TermManager1.TermView">

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" >
            <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <DatePicker Date="{Binding TermStartDate}" />
                <Editor Text="{Binding TermName}" />
                <DatePicker Date="{Binding TermEndDate}" />
            </FlexLayout>
            <SelectableItemsView x:Name="ClassesCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding classes}" >
                <SelectableItemsView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ClassName}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </SelectableItemsView.ItemTemplate>
            </SelectableItemsView>
            <FlexLayout>
                <Button Text="Add Class" Clicked="AddClassButton_OnClicked" />
                <Button Text="Delete Class" Clicked="DeleteClassButton_OnClicked" />
            </FlexLayout>
        </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

**Term class constructor & Class list**

```
 public List<Class> classes = new List<Class>();

        public Term(int termID)
        {
            this.TermId = termID;
            this.TermName = String.Concat("TermName", termID);
            this.classes.Add(new Class());
            this.classes.Add(new Class());
            this.classes.Add(new Class());
            this.classes.Add(new Class());

        }
```

Class class constructor

```
 public Class()
        {
            this.ClassName = "ClassName";
            this.ClassId = 0;
            this.ClassStatus = "Unset Status";
        }
```

Comment: when you add a bunch of new Class() objects - is that parameterless constructor actually setting the ClassName that you're binding to in your XAML?

Comment: Yes, it gives each Class a default value for their properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my issue with a variety of things. Firstly, I replaced the SelectableItemsView with a CollectionView. Then I changed my List of Classes to an ObservableCollection. And Lastly, I replaced the ViewCell in my TermView xaml with a StackLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just have to use INPC on this to work.

Change Classes to be an ObservableCollection instead of a List (note there's a ToObservableCollection extension available too).

Then for the Class object, just inherit from BindableObject and use OnPropertyChanged() in the setter for the properties you want to be updated, e.g.:

```
    private string _className;
    public string ClassName;
    {
        get => _className;
        set
        {
            _className = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged - you can just stick a INotifyPropertyChanged on your viewmodel class and then use regular auto-properties, e.g. public string ClassName { get; set; } , that will automatically have INPC implemented for you thanks to Fody.

Comment: I changed the List to a ObservableCollection, and converted my Term class and Class class to utilize INPC using the alternative method in this guide: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simplifying-mvvm-inotifypropertychanged-on-xamarin-forms/
Still not populating.

Answer (score -1):

> I've also tried using a ListView and its giving me the same problem.

According to your code, I see you add some Class in List classes, but you don't assign ClassName value, here is the sample about ListView:

```
public partial class Page30 : ContentPage
{
    public Page30 (int Id)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.BindingContext = new Term(Id);
    }
}

public class Term
{
    public List<Class1> classes { get; set; }
    public int TermId { get; set; }
    public string TermName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TermStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TermEndDate { get; set; }

    public Term(int TermId)
    {
        this.TermId = TermId;
        this.TermName = String.Concat("TermName", TermId);
        TermStartDate = new DateTime(2017,7,24);

        TermEndDate = new DateTime(2019,01,01);

        classes = new List<Class1>()
        {
            new Class1(){ClassName="class a"},
             new Class1(){ClassName="class b"},
              new Class1(){ClassName="class c"},
               new Class1(){ClassName="class d"},
                new Class1(){ClassName="class e"},
                 new Class1(){ClassName="class f"},
               new Class1(){ClassName="class g"},
        };          
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The Class constructor assigns all Class properties with a default value.

Comment: @C.Downer, please define one List<Class> type property,`public List<Class1> classes { get; set; }`, don't define field in Term class, then try it again.

Comment: Seems odd to post more problematic code as an answer - @CherryBu , kindly recommend not doing so.

Comment: @Mark, Do you try my code? I test my code at my side, but I don't find any issue. I can reproduce @C.Downer problem, so I suggest @C.Downer to define `public List<Class1> classes { get; set; }` instead of `public List<Class> classes = new List<Class>()`, because using binding.